# How to change values inside a span tag in Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to change the values inside the span tag in a shiny App based on dataframe

Dataframe

```
df <- tibble(
  Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19"),
  Heat_Capacity = c(159.65, 159.67, 159.68, 159.66, 159.70),
  Heat_Rate = c(-151.06, -151.07, -151.08, -151.09, -151.10),
  
)
```

Shiny Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-
  fluidPage(tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "./styles.css")),
            
            
            
            mainPanel(
                tags$div(class = "circle1",
                         tags$p("Heat Capacity"),
                         tags$span("")
                ),
                tags$div(class = "circle1",
                         tags$p("Heat Capacity"),
                         tags$span("")
                )
              )
              
             
            )
        
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm trying to display the values inside the dataframe  one by one in the span tag where the value changes every second or two when the Shiny App starts.

Desired Outcome Example:

[image: Desire Outcome Example]

****styles.css****

```
.circle1 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #11141a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 100px;
    
    /*flex box */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border: 3px solid #f1c40f;
   
}
        
.circle2 {
      width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #11141a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    right: 460px;
    
    
    
    /*flex box */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border: 3px solid #f1c40f;
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how `Date_Time` in your data frame relates to your problem, but you can use `textOutput` for a reactive `<span>`, update it in the server and use  `ìnvalidateLater` to set a timer like so (I removed the `css` as it has nothing to do with the problem at hand):

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
   Date_Time = c("2023-06-14 09:43:06", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", 
                 "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", 
                 "2023-06-14 09:43:19"),
   Heat_Capacity = c(159.65, 159.67, 159.68, 159.66, 159.70),
   Heat_Rate = c(-151.06, -151.07, -151.08, -151.09, -151.10)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
      tags$div(
         tags$p("Heat Capacity:",
                textOutput("value", inline = TRUE)
         ),
         tags$p("Time Stamp:",
                textOutput("timestamp", inline = TRUE)
         )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   act_index <- reactiveVal(1L)
   
   observe({
      val <- isolate(act_index())
      invalidateLater(1000,
                      session)
      new_val <- ifelse(val == nrow(df), 1L, val + 1L)
      act_index(new_val)
   })
   
   output$value <- renderText({
      df %>% 
         slice(act_index()) %>% 
         pull(Heat_Capacity)
   })
   
   output$timestamp <- renderText({
      df %>% 
         slice(act_index()) %>% 
         pull(Date_Time)
   })
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: To do more of these reactive  Shiny App. Do I need to learn more on javascript , Shiny or both

Comment: the point where you need javascript to *really* improve your app is still far. The vast majority of things can be done purely with Shiny. What couldn't hurt is to get familiar with HTML and CSS, since you explicitly asked for <span> and custom styling is always nice (and differentiates your apps from others ).